# Alternatives to Fetch When Dealing With mysqli prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following code which executes a MySQL query using prepared statements:

```
$selectStatement = "SELECT " . implode(", ", $allFields); // cat select w/ allFields
$stmnt = $mysqli->prepare($selectStatement . 
     "FROM Musicians WHERE name = ?");
$stmnt->bind_param('s', $name);
$stmnt.execute();
```

At this point, most of what I've read tells me that I should use `bind_result()` and then `fetch()` on $stmnt. However, I'd prefer to get an array filled with the values instead of iterating over a bunch of dumped variables, as `fetch()` does. Is there a way to get something similar to what `fetch_assoc()` would give me while using prepared statements and results?

Comment: Why you no set an array in the execute method?

Comment: Because it returns a boolean value and accepts no arguments?

Comment: take a look: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Comment: Hm. Looks similar to mysqli_stmt::getresult(), but both of them require something called sqlnd, which doesn't appear to be on the server I'm working on, and I can't handily install and reinstall PHP on this server. That seems to be the only way to install sqlnd...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, to use familiar fetch() with mysqli one have to call get_result() first and it is not always available.
Not to mention that you can't bind variable number of placeholders without some sophisticated code too.
Which makes **mysqli** absolutely **unusable** with **prepared statements**.

So, there are 2 solutions.

1. Do not use mysqli
2. Do not use prepared statements.

For the first option one go for PDO.
Unlike mysqli, it has [**everything you need from mysqli and much more**.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM Musicians WHERE name = ?");
$stm->execute(array($name));
$row = $stm->fetch(); // or fetchAll() depends on the numer of rows expected.
```

For the second you can use manually handled placeholders.
This approach will be even more useful than PDO, a real neat code:

```
$row = $db->getRow("SELECT * FROM Musicians WHERE name = ?s",$name);
```

Comment: This was the main reason why I chose PDO when I evaluated mysqli. Being able to fetch associative arrays in regular queries but not in parametrized queries is an absurd restriction. (If you agree with me, go and upvote [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/127218/13508) and bring some justice to the world.)

Answer (score 0):

To add a solution to clarify:

If we could choose the server at start, I prefer to use php-mysqlnd module, instead of php-mysql module, for PHP.  Then, we could use:

```
...
$stmnt.execute();
$res = $stmnt->get_result();
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
```

That seems simpler to me.